# if $f $ is continuous then is $\sqrt f $continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I just want to know if $f $ is continuous on a compact interval, then does it follow that $\sqrt f$ is also continuous?

Comment: Yes, you just compose two continuous functions. (I presume that $f$ takes non-negative values only.) See this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318614/composition-of-continuous-functions

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have to prove that $\sqrt{f}$ is a continuous function (where $f$ is continuous). We go by the definition of continuity. Take any $\epsilon>0$. Then,

$$
\left|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(y)}\right|^2=f(x)+f(y)-2\sqrt{f(x)f(y)}.
$$

Since $f$ should be non-negative,

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(y)}\right|^2&<f(x)+f(y)=\left|f(x)+f(y)\right|\\
\implies\quad\left|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(y)}\right|&<\sqrt{\left|f(x)+f(y)\right|}.
\end{align}
$$

Since $f$ is continuous we know that there exist a $\delta > 0$ such that,

$$
\left|f(x)+f(y)\right|<\epsilon^2\mbox{ whenever }|x-y|<\delta.
$$

Hence,

$$\left|\sqrt{f(x)}-\sqrt{f(y)}\right|<\sqrt{\left|f(x)+f(y)\right|}<\epsilon\mbox{ whenever }|x-y|<\delta$$

and $\sqrt{f}$ is also continuous.

Comment: Could you please explain why continuity implies that $|f(x)+f(y)| \lt \varepsilon^2$? I thought it was $|f(x)-f(y)| \lt \varepsilon^2$

Answer (score 4):

Well, if $f\colon K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is continuous, given that $\sqrt{\cdot} \ \colon \mathbb{R}_{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is also continuous, then so is their composition: $\sqrt{f} \ \colon K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ (without any assumptions about K)

Comment: Well you should at least assume $K$ is a topological space if you want the first statement to make sense.

Comment: True ... I was thinking of $K$ as a subset of the real line, and therefore, no special property (such as compactedness) was needed, but you're right.