# Show that $f = g-h$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Show that every continuous function $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as $f = g-h$ where $g,h$ are nonnegative and continuous.

We have three cases. Either $f$ is strictly, nonnegative, nonpositive, or both. In the first case we can always break up a continuous function $f$ as $f = f-0$. Thus since $f$ and $0$ are continuous we are done. I am unsure about the other two cases, though.

Comment: Hint: You can write down $g$ and $h$ explicitly in terms of $f$ using case statements.

Answer (score 4):

$f^{+}:=\max\{f,0\}$ ($\max$ taken pointwise) is continuous, since

$$f^{+}=\frac{|f|+f}{2}.$$

Analogously, $f^{-}:=-\min\{f,0\}$ is also continuous. Note that $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$.

Comment: How do you know $f^+$ is continuous?

Comment: Because of the equality after "since". $f^{+}$ is the sum of two continuous functions, divided by a constant.

Comment: How do you know that $|f|$ is continuous?

Comment: Do you know that the module function is continuous? If so, $|f|$ is the composition of the module function with $f$. Proving that the module function is continuous (if you don't know it) should be an easy exercise.

Comment: Basically are you saying since $f$ is continuous, so is $|f|$?

Comment: That's correct. Note that the converse doesn't necessarily hold.

Comment: Hmm, can someone give me a proof of that?

Comment: @Puzzled417 It suffices to know two facts:

1- Composition of continuous functions is continuous; 2- The map $g$ which makes $x \mapsto |x|$ (that is, the "module" function) is continuous. Because then, $|f|=g \circ f$.

Comment: @Puzzled417 See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/318614/201168).

Comment: $\vert \vert f(x) \vert-\vert f(x_0) \vert \vert \le \vert f(x)- f(x_0) \vert $