# Establishing Continuity of $\cos x$ based on Continuity of $\sin x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, continuity

If we have established that $\lim_{x\to c} \sin x = \sin c$, is it enough to argue that $\cos x$ is just a translation of $\sin x$ in order to establish that $\lim_{x\to c} \cos x = \cos c$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think that's right. Since sin(x) is continuous for all $x\in \mathbb R$, a translation of sin(x) must also be continuous for the same domain

Comment: A translation is a continuous operation, and compositions of continuous functions are continuous.

Comment: Either you know $lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \lim_{x\to c+v} f(x - v)$ or you have to prove it.  If you know it, state it.  If you don't, prove it.  Unless you aren't show if it's true.... in which case, figure out if it is true.

Answer (score 3):

Yes since the composition of continuous function is continuous and we have

$$\cos x = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)$$

with $\frac{\pi}2-x$ continuous, we can conclude that $\cos x$ also is continuous.

Refer also to the related:

- [composition of continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318614/505767)
- [Real Analysis: Continuity of a Composition Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527855/505767)