# Composition of two Riemann integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f,g$ are two Riemann  Integrable functions .Is it true that $f\circ g$ is also Riemann  Integrable?

Trying this for a long time but not getting the answer

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread the problem.

Comment: If you could say, where your problem here is, maybe somebody could help.

Comment: Yes it happens to all@DavidMitra

Comment: my problem is I cant prove this @Karl

Comment: See Example 9 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA44&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false). (The "function $f$ of Example 15" mentioned is [Thomae's Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function))

Comment: See answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306326/composition-of-riemann-integrable-functions), also [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20045/about-the-riemann-integrability-of-composite-functions)

Comment: @learning maths you don't understand. What is your problem in proving this? Or do you want a complete solution without any efforts from your side?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMitra your answer is mind blowing.Deeply astonished by your knowledge of mathematics

Answer (score 83):

A function on a bounded interval is Riemann-integrable iff it is bounded and almost everywhere continuous. So the functions
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ for }x \ne 0 \\ 0 & \text{ for } x = 0  \end{cases}
\quad \text{ and } \quad
g(x) = \begin{cases} 1/q & \text{ for }x=p/q \\ 0 & \text{ for } x \notin \mathbb{Q}  \end{cases}
$$
are Riemann-integrable over any bounded interval, since $f$ is continuous everywhere except at $0$, and $g$ is continuous at every irrational $x$. (In the definition $x=p/q$ is the unique representation of rational $x$ with $p$ and $q$ relatively prime integers and $q>0$.)

The composition of these functions is
$$
f(g(x)) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ for }x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{ for } x \notin \mathbb{Q}  \end{cases}
$$
which is nowhere continuous, so not Riemann-integrable over any interval.

Comment: Thanks for your effort sir but my problem has been solved by David Mitra

Comment: That's fine there are lots of other people who benefit from this answer

Comment: Does anyone have a reference for why g(x) above is continuous on IR/IQ ? Does it have to do with, if you want to approximate an irrational with rationals, the denominator of those irrationals has to go to infinity (if you bound the denominator, you don't find enough numbers)?

Comment: @dasWesen: Basically yes, and this function even has its own Wikipedia page, with a formal proof of continuity/discontinuity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function

Comment: @LukasGeyer Thank you!

Comment: @LukasGeyer The composition we get here is not a Reimann Integrable function but is a Lebesgue measurable function, Is it true in Lebesgue case?

Comment: @Sushant; Compositions of Lebesgue-measurable functions need not be Lebesgue measurable. Even the composition of Lebesgue measurable and homeomorphism need not be, because a homeomorphism can map a non-measurable set into a Lebesgue null set. However, compositions of Borel-measurable functions are again Borel-measurable.