# Is $g\circ f$ integrable if $f$ is increasing and $g$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[a, b] \to \Bbb R$ be increasing and $g:f[a, b] \to \Bbb R$ be integrable. Is $g\circ f$ integrable on $[a, b]$?

It seems integrable to me since $g$ is integrable on $[f(a),f(b)]$ since for any partition $P'$ of $[a,b]$, we can choose partition $P''$ of $[f(a),f(b)]$ such that
$$U(g\circ f,P')−L(g\circ f,P')≤U(g,P'')−L(g,P'')$$
Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: You can show without any heavy machinery that an increasing (or any monotone) function is integrable. Does that help?

Comment: @SabyasachiBasu It doesn't, $g \circ f$ can be not Riemann integrable even if $g$ is integrable and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Adayah yeah you're right, it's fairly easy to come up with a counter example.

Comment: I did a quick google search and found [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1338515233).

Comment: @SabyasachiBasu I can show that $f\circ g$ may not be integrable.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path It's given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060834/composition-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions) $f\circ g$ is not integrable where $f$ is increasing and $g$ is integrable.

Comment: @HashNuke Perhaps, but the bottom line of the discussion is that your problem has $g\circ f$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Yup, i get the feeling that this is integrable.

Comment: User Boshu also got you the reading that it may not be, but feel free.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I am checking it :)

Answer (score 1):

$$f:[0,1]\to[0,1] ,\quad  f(x) = x^2 $$
$$ g: [0,1] \to \mathbb R ,\quad g = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt x} & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases} $$

Notice that $f$ is increasing, $g$ is integrable, while $g\circ f$ is not integrable.

Comment: $g$ is not bounded and according my definition of my book, Riemann integrability only applied to bounded function. This is from Abbott Understanding Analysis  page 227

Comment: @HashNuke fair, but it seems UserS has edited your question to add measure-theory as a tag. If you don't agree with him, you should undo his edit.