# Composite of non Riemann integrable functions can be Riemann integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration

(1) Let $f,g$ be not Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and the range of $f$ is $[a,b]$ also. Can we find an example such that $g\circ f(x)=g(f(x))$ is Riemann integrable  on $[a,b]$?

(2) Let $f,g$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and the range of $f$ is $[a,b]$ also. Can we show that $g\circ f$ is Riemann integrable  on　 $[a,b]$ also?

Comment: Also, please avoid multiple questions in a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1, $$f(x)=g(x)=
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      x, &x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 
      1-x,&x\notin \mathbb{Q} \\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\\$$and $[a,b]=[0,1]$.

For question 2, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060834/composition-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions).
In order to change the range of $f$, alter it to
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1/q & \text{ for }x=p/q\text{ and $0\le x\le1/2$} \\ 0 & \text{ for } x \notin \mathbb{Q}\text{ and $0\le x\le1/2$}\\
2x-1 & \text{others}  \end{cases}
$$ and the $g$ desired is the $f$ in my link.

Comment: question 2, there is another condition: the range of $f$ is $[a,b]$.

Comment: @xldd edited. Please check.

Comment: @Chen What is the outer function and the inner function? It really troubles me.

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060834/composition-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions, the inner function is the Riemann function, whose range is not all of $[0,1]$, and the $f$ is the outer function, which seems you have changed to be here.

Comment: For question2, the outer function is $f$, and the inner function is the $g$ in my link.

Comment: But in my question, the range of the inner function is all of $[a,b]$.

Comment: It is not hard to alter the inner function. Try to do it yourself. Anyway I edited it for correctness.