# counter example for composition of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Give an example to show that integrability is not preserved by composition; that is, give an example
>   of two bounded real-valued functions f on an interval [a, b] ⊂ R and g on an interval [c, d] ⊂ R
>   containing f([a, b]) such that $\int_a^bf$ and $\int_c^dg$ exists
>   $\int _a^bg ◦ f$ does not.

I thought about Riemann function, Dirichlet function and topologist's sine function but none of these works..

Could you please think of any?

Comment: What type of integral are you using? If Riemann, see this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060834/composition-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks a lot

Comment: How about trying a simple rational function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composition of two Riemann integrable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060834/composition-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions)