# Construct an example of a composition

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to prove that, unlike the reversed case, composition of a Riemann integrable function and a continuous function might be non-integrable. I saw an example of such a function, but, honestly, the choice of function seemed like magic.

How can I build an example? For example, the outer function could be some indicator function. If I understand correctly, the inner function's range should be a set of positive measure. The first function will then be 1 if the argument is in the set, or else zero.

I would appreciate any hints. Thank you

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306326/composition-of-riemann-integrable-functions) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier in my mind to start with what we are trying to build, e.g. a function that is not Riemann integrable. For instance $\frac1{|x|}$. Then notice that $|x|=\sqrt{|x|^2}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ is Riemann integrable  (locally, around 0).